# How Can we Correct ,Incorrect Gmail Email Address in PHP

Tags: php, email

I want to check Gmail, email address of a person that is correct or not, If not correct make it correct. I want to check only last part of email address that is after "@" 
For example,

```
1] xyz@gail.com -> Incorrect, make it correct to xyz@gmail.com
2] abx@gmailcom ->  Incorrect, make it correct to abx@gmail.com
3] avd@gmil.com -> Incorrect, make it correct to avd@gmail.com
```

Comment: Store incorrect variants in an array and replace'em.

Comment: provide your php code..what have you tried till now

Comment: `if (partAfter@ != 'gmail') { replaceWith(gmail) }`

Comment: Why would you want to implement such a specific verification? Why not use existing approaches to email addresses in general? Why the limitation to the gmail service?

Comment: @arkascha I want to verify for every Email account like Gmail,Yahoo and so on. Can you suggest me some way to correct it.

Comment: For a lexical analysis I suggest you start reading the official documentation of the tools you are trying to use: http://php.net/manual/de/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: Also there are some implementations that do a live check to see if a message will get accepted. A questionable practice, but certainly possible. Examples are: https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail or https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html